# R Shiny: Kill from vbs script

Tags: r, shiny

I'm running a shiny app locally, starting it from a vbs script.
Is there a way to end the app when the user closes the browser window?
Something like end when it detects a connection reset. It looks like it can detect resets because i get the following when closing the browser while running the app from R:

```
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

Comment: You are looking for `onSessionEnded`, I think. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276491/how-to-implement-a-cleanup-routine-in-r-shiny.  OR alternative: https://www.r-bloggers.com/stop-shiny-and-close-browser-together/

Comment: Great, works well. I've added a comment with full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment to my question, here is the solution:

I added this to my server.r file:

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
  quit()
})
```