# Cleanup when `global.R` variables are deleted

Tags: r, callback, shiny, resource-cleanup, r6

## Question

From the documentation it is clear, that variables in `server.R` have a different life span than the ones in `global.R`.

For cleanup operations in `server`, there is the `session$onSessionEnded` callback function. An example to use this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276491/how-to-implement-a-cleanup-routine-in-r-shiny).

> Is there something similar for the `global.R` script?

## Context

In my setup, I have two variables with reference semantics (instances of `R6` classes) in the global scope that need cleanup. The cleanup operation is dependend on both objects. Some pseudocode.

```
# context global.R
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A = classA$new()
B = classB$new()

# call after the last sesion has ended
cleanupFunction = function(){
  # call this before B$finalize()
  A$saveToSQL(B)
  A$finalize()
}
```

`A` and `B` are both operaing on `server.R`.

---

## Current workaround

Since both `classA` and `classB` are `R6` classes, I have access to the `finalize` method (a destructor in `C++` terms). So the following workaround is possible.

```
classA$finalize = function(){
  if(cleanupFlag){
    cleanupFunction()
    cleanupFlag <<- FALSE
  }
}

classB$finalize = function(){
  if(cleanupFlag){
    cleanupFunction()
    cleanupFlag <<- FALSE
  }
}
```

This requires me to use callbacks already because of scoping.

---

If someone knows a "proper" way to solve this, I would be very interested.